# Unable to install git and related plugins in Jenkins using Ansible

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins, ansible

I am trying to install the following Jenkins plugins(while installing Jenkins) using Ansible

> git,git-client,ssh,scm-api,shiningpanda plugin

After execution packages `ssh, scm-api, shiningpanda plugins` got installed.`git and git-client` are not in the list of installed plugins.
Below is the code and link to the the code I have used:

```
- name: Get the jenkins-cli jarfile from the Jenkins server
  get_url:
    url: "http://{{host-name}}:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar"
    dest: "/opt/jenkins-cli.jar"
  register: jarfile_get
  until: "'OK' in jarfile_get.msg or 'file already exists' in jarfile_get.msg"
  retries: 5
  delay: 10

- name: Install Jenkins plugins
  command: >
    java -jar /opt/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://{{host-name}}:8080/ install-plugin {{ item }}
    creates=/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/{{ item }}.jpi
  with_items: jenkins_plugins
  notify: restart jenkins

- name: Force a change of owner for all plugins
  shell: chown -R konfilarity:konfilarity /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/*
  notify: restart jenkins
```

Link to the ansible script referred :[Install-jenkins-plugin-ansible](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-jenkins/blob/master/tasks/plugins.yml)

Comment: Can you post the output of the Ansible execution? Did it show any errors?

Comment: it gave the following output when I ran on the vagrant machine having the ip:192.168.33.14:


TASK: [build_server_jenkins | Install Jenkins plugins] ************************ 

    skipping: [192.168.33.14] => (item=credentials)

    skipping: [192.168.33.14] => (item=ssh-credentials)

    changed: [192.168.33.14] => (item=git-client)

    changed: [192.168.33.14] => (item=git)

    changed: [192.168.33.14] => (item=ssh)

    skipping: [192.168.33.14] => (item=scm-api)

    changed: [192.168.33.14] => (item=shiningpanda)

    changed: [192.168.33.14] => (item=test-results-analyzer)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to add `register: jenkins_output` and `failed_when:` clauses to the Jenkins command task, and have the failed_when inspect `jenkins_output.stdout` and `jenkins_output.stderr` for success/fail. I don't know about install-plugin, but many of the Jenkins-cli commands don't return a non-zero exit code on failure, so Ansible has no idea it broke.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked:

```
 - name: Force a change of owner for all plugins
      shell: chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/*
```

The only reason was the owner and group were not jenkins.